# MongoDB - How to handle users reading a news alert

Tags: mongodb

Let's say I have a service with thousands of users, and I want to post news alerts that they can view. Once they view one, it's marked as seen (for just that user, obviously).

I think I know the answer to this, but is it better to store on the news item a list of users who have seen it? Or is it better to store on the user document a list of all news items they've seen?

I'm assuming the latter is better, mostly because if I have 20,000 users, that means if all of them have seen a particular news alert, then I've got an array of 20,000 IDs stored in that news alert document, which probably isn't good. But this structure seems better:

```
{
  email: 'person@person.net',
  name: 'Person',
  seenNews: [
    'TTJGGiPsTqqLio4sf',
    'vhePmuShra3MSzYsu',
    'JKFqqCKDmtuuoQBXu',
    'gCFyzu8BAihj8NnXB'
  ]
}
```

I probably won't have more than a few hundred news items, plus I can always go back and delete old ones anyway.

Or is there an even better way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you have news

```
{
  _id: "Fubar2.0",
  title: "Fubar 2.0 released"
}
```

and users

```
{
  _id: "12345",
  name: "CoolName"
}
```

storing what has been seen in either of the above models would sooner or later exceed the BSON document size limit of 16MB. Furthermore, increasing documents in size isn't efficiently handled with the mmapv1 storage engine, which is still the default.

Conclusion: you need to store the news read in separate documents in a seen collection:

```
{
  _id: {
   newsitem: "Fubar2.0",
   user:"12345"
  }
}
```

Since we have a compound `_id` for seen, which is automatically indexed (and held in RAM as long as possible), queries are quite efficient.

The problem is obvious: you need two queries to get news unseen by a user

```
var seen = new Array()
db.seen.find({"_id.user":"12345"},{_id:1}).forEach(
  function(doc){
    seen.push(doc._id.news);
  }
)
var unseen = db.news.find({_id: {$nin: seen}})
```

While this works and imho is the proper solution for the situation described, the "unseen" query isn't very efficient.

Depending on the use case, you could rather go with something like this for users

```
{
  _id:"12345",
  name: "CoolName",
  lastSeen: ISODate("2015-05-05T03:26:36Z")
}
```

and news like this

```
{
  _id:{
    title:"FuBar 2.0 released",
    date: ISODate("2015-05-05T03:46:00Z")
  }
}
```

So when a user logs in, you already loaded the user document, right? With this, you can get all the news he or she presumably hasn't seen with

```
db.news.find({"_id.date":{$gte: user.lastSeen} })
```

Admittedly you can not really check which user has seen which news item, but if the goal is to make sure the user is presented with all the news since his or her last visit, the latter solution is efficient and easy to implement (and scale).